# f# file not running

Tags: twitter, f#, extract

I am a noob when it comes to f#, I am a phd student in Maths and I am trying to run the following:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2011/03/10/slides-and-demo-scripts-for-sigcse.aspx

Under the zip file Demos/TwitterFeed/.....
I am trying to run the files in the TwitterFeed. I have never used f# and when I try to run it under visualstudio shell I get errors. Could anybody please help me.

Thanks,

Mohit

Comment: TwitterStream.fsx(9,1): error FS0079: Could not load file 'c:\users\mohit\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\..\..\TwitterPassword.fs' because it does not exist or is inaccessible

Comment: well, do you have TwitterPassword.fs in that directory? If you don't, just move it there

Comment: It is already in the directory! If you could have a look by downloading the zip file I would really appreciate it if you can run it and see if you get same error. Thanks Mauricio

Answer (score 0):

In twitterstream.fsx, change the #load directive for twitterpassword.fs to the following:

```
#load "TwitterPassword.fs"
```

This should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error then when I try to run Twitter stream...

TwitterStream.fsx(1,1): error FS0010: Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in interaction

Comment: Have you added your Twitter username/password? Change the Line 18 in TwitterFeed.fsx to your username/password. I hope you are running it interactively, since it is intended to be run like that.  Please watch Don Syme's presentation, if you're not sure how.